# MySql Query not run when there is a comment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-injection

I am trying to simulate an SQL injection attack on my own database by inserting SQL code into the input spaces.

My SQL code is:

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE username = '...' 
AND password = '...';
```

where ... is the input.

I am trying to use the following input to select every user and LIMIT that output to 1.

Here is the username input:

```
' OR ''='
```

This should get all the usernames.

And here is the password input:

```
' OR ''='' LIMIT 1; --
```

This should first get all the passwords, then limit the output to just 1 row, and then comment the final `';`

So the code executed should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE username = '' OR ''='' 
AND password = '' OR ''='' LIMIT 1; -- ';
```

This does not work for some reason. I am using SequelPro and it tells me it's running 2 queries and not outputting anything. The second query being `-- ';`

However, if I remove that last part and just run up until the first semicolon, it works and retrieves a single user from the database.

What is going on?

Comment: I think the error is clear.  You are trying to run two queries, but the API only allows 1.  You need to remove the middle semicolon.

Comment: read about php mysql api and multiple Statements. It is not allowed

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you. I was confused though, because the second semicolon is just a comment. I didn't realise that counts as another statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is all right, and the problem you have is from SequelPro which parser appears to be a blunt one, taking a comment for another query.

To avoid this confusion better take out the trailing semicolon from the forged input